# how to break lines for a value from database

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

i want to break line between command and result :

```
outputs.append(output)
    outputs.append(request.POST.get("cmds"))    
    device.config = outputs 
    device.save()
```

i added the value 'outputs' in device.config
and this is my template i use {{device.config|linebreaksbr}}

but this is the result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to show console output of the web is the use of `<pre>` tag, like this

```
<pre>{{device.config}}</pre>
```